# Can I safely remove Expedited SSL after installing a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have obtained an SSL cert from Lets Encrypt and added it to my SSL endpoint on Heroku, but I'm a bit nervous about simply removing Expedited SSL. Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

No problem with doing that and switching to a new certificate from differente Certificate Authority (CA) such as LetsEncrypt. I always remove the references to the old certificates.
A practice I suggest is moving the old certificates to new ones by appending the .backup at the end

Based on the [documentation](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/expeditedssl) this is a correct practice as long as DNS is pointed to the right endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my old Comodo SSL certificate and it worked fine. Make sure you've updated your DNS Target at your domain registrar to point to the SSL endpoint you got when you added the Let's Encrypt cert. (Usually `certified.domain.herokudns.com`)