# Recommendations to remove SSL certificate and generate one with Letsencrypt NGINX on ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot

I would like to learn some approach for doing the following: 
I must remove ComodoSSL certificate from some nginx running on ubuntu 18. I want to eliminate as much traces as possible from Comodo. After the removal process Letsencrypt will be used to generate a free certificate. Someone has a similar question but considering a post-scenario when the certificate is already installed and there are 2 certificates. [Reference to other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264625/can-i-safely-remove-expedited-ssl-after-installing-a-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificat/41445315#41445315)
I plan this:

1. I dont know the server much so i ran `dpkg -l | less` to find some references to comodo pacakages and i couldnt find anything
2. edit the nginx config file in /sites-available to remove references to the old certificate
3. install letscencryp utility certbot
4. generate certificate for domain and FQDN example.io and www.example.io [letsencrypt question on doing this certificate generation but for apache](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/everything-to-https-www-example-com/79461/14)
5. Generate certificate with letsencrypt certbot
6. modify the NGINX configuration file to point to the letsencrypt certificate paths
7. test with wget utility

> ```
> wget www.recover.example.com
>
> wget recover.example.com
>
> wget https://www.recover.example.com/
>
> wget https://recover.example.com
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The only artifacts relating to Comodo will be the SSL certificate and key listed in your nginx.conf files (ssl_certificate_key and ssl_certificate and parameters).

Once you enroll for a certificate via Let’s Encrypt (check out https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh) you can update your Nginx config to point at those files and then delete the files that had the Comodo Related certificate and keys.

Schedule the Let’s Encrypt (acme.sh, etc) client to run periodically and then you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to install a wildcard certificate and I found the following reference from LetsEncrypt the most helpful.:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/wildcard-domain-step-by-step/58250